# MongoDB Atlas SSL handshake failed:

Tags: mongodb, ssl, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I can connect to mongodb atlas db through the mongosh shell, however I get an error when trying to access through the pymongo driver. This is the connection string:

```
mongodb+srv://<user:<password>@cluster0.j1tlk.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

And this the error I am getting:

```
SSL handshake failed: cluster0-shard-00-00.j1tlk.mongodb.net:27017: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed'
```